# A NodeJS script fails to run on Windows or Linux

Tags: linux, node.js, windows, mongodb

In one of our internal project, I am failing to run the `server.js` with this error. I am trying it on Windows, however Ubuntu also gives the same.

Why I am facing this?

```
$ node src\server\server.js                                                                                 
Launching http server...                                                                                    
Connecting to database...                                                                                   
Listening on port 9090...                                                                                   
c:\projectAlpha\node_modules\mongodb\lib\server.js:242                                                  
        process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })                                                         
                                      ^                                                                     

TypeError: callback is not a function                                                                       
    at c:\projectAlpha\src\server\mongo_db.js:15:4                                                      
    at c:\projectAlpha\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:330:20                                  
    at c:\projectAlpha\node_modules\mongodb\lib\db.js:231:14                                            
    at null.<anonymous> (c:\projectAlpha\node_modules\mongodb\lib\server.js:240:9)                      
    at g (events.js:273:16)                                                                                 
    at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)                                                                           
    at emit (events.js:185:7)                                                                               
    at null.<anonymous> (c:\projectAlpha\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:218:12)     
    at g (events.js:273:16)                                                                                 
    at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
```

Answer (score 0):

I failed to get any direct help online. *Hence, thought to put it here for others.*

After a bit of research, I suspected it may something related to `MongoDB` as I don't had it installed on my system but this specific project needed that.

So, I downloaded `MongoDB`(community edition) and installed it.

Then, created a data folder, and ran it as a service.

```
$ cd c:\
$ md \data\db
$ "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin\mongod.exe" --dbpath c:\data
```

voilà, problem solved. `$ node src\server\server.js` ran nicely.